# How to return a new list that contains just odd elements from data using only recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have been asked to:

Write a function odds(data) that takes a list of ints, data, as a parameter and returns a new list that contains just the odd elements from data, i.e. those elements that are not exactly divisible by two. Your code must not use for or while and must not import anything.

This is my current code:

```
def odds(data):
    """Returns a new list that contains just the odd elements from the data"""
    odd_nums = []
    if len(data) == 1:
        return []
    
    if data[0] % 2 != 0:   
        odd_nums.append(data[0])
    return odds(data[1:])
```

Test codes:

```
print(odds(\[0, 1, 12, 13, 14, 9, -11, -20\]))

---\> \[1, 13, 9, -11\]
```

I am not sure how to recursively keep adding to the odd_nums list.

Comment: Can you use list comprehensions? Like:  [f for f in data if f%2 == 1]

Comment: Try initializing `odd_nums = []` above the function. And print it right after the call to `odds`

Comment: Can you explain why you need recursion for this? It's functionally achievable without that complication

Comment: Just for practice, I am currently learning content in my course about recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def odds(data):
    if not data:
        return []
    head = [ data[0] ] if data[0]%2==1 else []
    if len(data)>1:
        return head + odds (data[1:])
    else:
        return head
    
print(odds([0, 1, 12, 13, 14, 9, -11, -20]))
```

You almost had it. Just combine lists. potentially empty lists are fine.

Comment: I get an IndexError when testing with print(odds([])) an empty list. I've tried to implement how to add in the base case for this with your code, but I'm struggling.

Comment: Updated. try... except would be more pythonic, but let's not make it too obvious you are just copying from the net